# Sending javascript function with JSON is possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, callback, highcharts

I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/) to display charts: when the document is ready an ajax request will fetch the data (JSON format) and initialize the `chart` object with some default data and some dynamic data (points):

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var chart;

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('stats_update') }}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            data.chart.renderTo = 'chart'; // id of the div element
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(data); // inizialize chart object
        }
    });

}); // end of document.ready
```

So far so good all works fine except when i have to send back some **callbacks**. It's not working and i can't find why. The chart "freezes" and no tooltip is displayed:

**This is how the formatter function callback should be initialized (working):**

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() { return this.x; }
});
```

**This is how i send back the callback using JSON: Twig template engine outputting JSON, manually - no json_encode (not working):**

```
{
   "tooltip" : {
      "formatter" : "function() { return this.x; }"
   }
}
```

There are no errors in JSON parsing with jQuery. I'd admin i'm not a javascript nor jQuery guru... thanks for helping.

Comment: You are just passing a string back in that json. `tooltip.formatter` is not going to be a function, it will be a string with the value "`function() { return this.x; }`".

Comment: Why do you have to send a function in a JSON response?

Comment: @JaredFarrish because using a template i can send back the entire chart object (including actual data and callbacks), do partial refresh, use template inheritance to easily get a large variety of charts at a minimum cost.

Comment: Isn't that an overhead, sending back the whole `options` object instead of just the "data" every time you need to update the chart? That might not bother performance wise but sure does look like a misuse. You can have everything defined in Javascript for the `options` object once and just send back the data every time you need to update the chart.

Comment: @BheshGurung sending back the whole object is necessary if the user want to switch (again using ajax) to another chart type (e.g. from pie to bar). Each chart type has different options.

Comment: @Gremo: How is the user going to switch (using ajax)?

Comment: @BheshGurung i don't understand your question. The user simply choose a chart from a list (maybe a list of links) and an ajax request will fetch new chart + options.

Answer (score 3):

the function from your twig template is output as a string instead of a function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('stats_update') }}", 
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        data.chart.renderTo = 'chart'; // id of the div element
        data.tooltip.formatter = eval('(' + data.tooltip.formatter + ')');
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(data); // inizialize chart object
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't output it as a function because the resulting JSON would be invalid without quotes... am i missing something?

Comment: Its a bit hackish but you could do this `    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('stats_update') }}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            data.chart.renderTo = 'chart'; // id of the div element
            data.tooltip.formatter = eval('(' + data.tooltip.formatter + ')')
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(data); // inizialize chart object
        }
    });`

Comment: Pros and cons of this solution? Alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize a function with JavaScript / JSON.

Comment: So what's the best option i have? Define a general function in the page and the send only the callback name?

Comment: @Gremo: The best way to serialize your data will vary depending on the specific problem. There isn't a broad solution in this case.

Comment: I've already chosen how to serialize my data, that is getting it from database and transforming (thought Twig template) in JSON. The only problem is how to make the charts have their own function, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of requesting the whole `options` object from the server, I would request just the data and create the chart as follows -

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var chart;

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('stats_update') }}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ // <--- send just the data array from server

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart'; // id of the div element
                },
                //...                    
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() { 
                        return this.x; 
                    }
                },
                //...
                series: [{
                    data: eval('(' + data + ')')
                }]
            }); // inizialize chart object
        }
    });

}); // end of document.ready
```